# Wysiwyg for dynamic blocks of content?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wysiwyg, usability

I'm wondering how I could make a page type of 3 columns where I can add blocks of texts and for each block I could choose to add content to either sides of the block of text.

So by default I would have a block of text in the middle column, and optionally in one or both side of that text, on the same level.

I could just do this in code each time I have to add a page. But I'm just wondering if there's a better more userfriendly way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I can add text to a page through a wysiwyg, but I need to be able to add content to a specific side (or both) of a paragraph inside my text, so that's why I'm talking about blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu could use divs (styles to make them appear as 3 columns not provided):

```
<div id="wrapperDIV">
    <div id="col1">column 1</div>
    <div id="col2">column 2</div>
    <div id="col3">column 3</div>
</div>
```

or what i prefer is tables:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you would create a wysiwyg editor into each column.  There are tons of tutorials out there on how to use javascript/iframes/etc to create an RTF editor.

You'll then have to learn how to connect to a database of some sort using php and then save what the user entered into the rtf editor into the database to display it later.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. And I think I can do it with your method but instead of an editor for each column I will created an editor for each row (table row). So I will make a +/- to add or remove editors/rows. merge them before I save it to one textfield. And if I have side content I will add a class to it to let it indent 200px or so left or right. If I need to edit the page I will split the text according to <article class="block"> and have dynamic editors. If that will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a content management service (CMS). Easiest solution is to use something like "WordPress" to allow you to edit your content - you can pick your layout (3 columsn if you so choose), and many other customizations.

Comment: I could do it in wordpress but I would rather just make it in php just for learning the language. besides the 3 column structure won't let me choose where to display a side content as the sidebars are seperated from my main content

Comment: so you want the html code to show content in 3 columns?  some would argue that you should use <div /> tags, but i personally prefer to use table columns because sometimes the div tag will line wrap on you, dependin on the browser. Lemme create a new post for that code